# How do I return null if my string has no null terminator

Tags: c

this is my first time posting here so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a C programme that allocates a pool, then stores a char array, "Hello World", in memory and then retrieves it. One of the lines of the code in my main method reads:

```
store(pool, 50, sizeof(str) - 1, str);
```

(my store method variables are (Pool *pool, int offset, int size, void *object)

If I am reading this correctly, then the pool being allocated is 1 less than the string size, so cutting of the \0 that would be on the end.

How do I check that character is missing off the end and return null because of it?

```
/* _POOL - pool 
 * int size - the size of the pool in bytes
 * void* ipPool - pointer to memory malloc'd by the operating system 
 */

typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
} Pool;

/* Allocate a memory pool of size n bytes from system memory (i.e., via malloc()) 
 * and return a pointer to the filled data Pool structure */
Pool* allocatePool(int n)
{
    if(n <= 0)
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    Pool *pool = malloc(sizeof *pool);

    if(!pool)
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    pool->size = n;

    if(!(pool->memory = malloc(n)))
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    return pool;
};

/* Free a memory pool allocated through allocatePool(int) */
void freePool(Pool *pool)
{
    if(!pool)
    {
             return;
    }

    if(pool->memory)
    {
            free(pool->memory);
    }

    free(pool);
};

/* Store an arbitrary object of size n bytes at
 * location offset within the pool */
void store(Pool *pool, int offset, int size, void *object)
{
    if(!pool)
    {
            return;
    }

    if(size + offset > pool->size)
    {
            return;
    }

    memcpy(pool + offset, object, size);
};

/* Retrieve an arbitrary object of size n bytes 
 * from a location offset within the pool */
void *retrieve(Pool *pool, int offset, int size)
{
    if(!pool)
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    void *obj = malloc(size);

    if(!obj)
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    if(size + offset > pool->size)
    {
            return NULL;
    }

    return memcpy(obj,  pool + offset, size);
};

void main()
{
    const int poolSize = 500;
    Pool* pool;
    int x = 5;
    char c = 'c';
    char str[] = "Hello World";

    /* Should retrieve Hello World */
    store(pool, 8, sizeof(str), str);
    printf("Test 4: Store an arbitrary multi-byte value\n");
    printf("\tStored: %s\n", str);
    printf("\tRetrieves: %s\n", (char*)retrieve(pool, 8, sizeof(str)));

    /* Should retrieve null */
    store(pool, 50, sizeof(str) - 1, str);
    printf("Test 5: Store an arbitrary multi-byte value with no null terminator\n");
    printf("\tStored: %s\n", str);
    printf("\tRetrieves: %s\n", (char*)retrieve(pool, 50, sizeof(str) - 1));
};
```

is all the code that I think is involved. This is currently putting in Hello World and retrieving Hello World.

I cannot edit any of the main method, only the contents of the functions and the struct.

Comment: If you show source code, make sure it is a simple self-contained example. Your example is just a oneliner calling a function of which we know only the signature. How did you allocate the memory pool points to?

Comment: It is unlikely that `sizeof(str) - 1` is useful, more likely is `strlen(str) + 1`

Comment: But strlen fails if the trailing null character is missing.

Comment: @TheBlastOne yes of course. OP should just have a look through the array passed as length `sizeof(str)` to see if it has a `nul`.

Comment: Is the `str` null-terminated when you pass it to `store()` ? If yes, use `strlen() + 1` for the length. If not, fix that.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. And it also has no string type. It is all convention, which you break.

Comment: sizeof (str) is constant. It is not the size of the block str points to. it is the size, in bytes, of the pointer stored in str, which is constant.

Comment: @TheBlastOne `char str[] = "Hello World";` so `sizeof str` will be the memory occupied by the text + terminator.

Comment: @Dylzan why are you worried? `"Hello World"` *does* have a terminator, and `sizeof str` includes that in its length. That is, defined as `char str[] = "Hello World";` but if the definition was `char *str = "Hello World";` then TheBlastOne would be right, `sizeof str` would be the size of the pointer, not the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane `str` in C is just a pointer to the start of a character array, so `sizeof str` will only return the size of that pointer (which is usually the 4 or 8 byte address that it is implemented as). C has no special knowledge of a `string` type and the only way it knows how long a string of characters is is that it ends with a null type - unlike C# and Java, which store a length beforehand.

Comment: @Compynerd255 please try it before commenting. `char str[] = "Hello World"; printf("%zu", sizeof str);` will output `12`. You are confusing arrays with pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane I stand corrected there. But it still isn't good practice because the pointer type (which is otherwise semantically equivalent) will return 4 or 8. And that will fail in OP's constraints, since main() is the only one who has the array size.

Comment: @Compynerd255 that is why you have to pass the array length to the function. Arrays and pointers are **not** semanticaly equivalent.

Comment: @Dylzan Could you give us the function contracts you were given, writing them as comments above the functions in your code? This would be the same sort of information found in `///` comments in C# programs and in Linux `man` pages.

Comment: @Dylzan That is helpful (though you should probably put those comments on multiple lines). Is this for a school project? If so, the assignment directions should have lots more information, including specific edge cases that need to be handled, as well as the expected results from the test output.

Comment: @Dylzan Yes, but what are tests 4 and 5 supposed to print if you have implemented the solution correctly? (Put those as comments next to each println statement)

Comment: Just putting an observation into the mix - in the function store(...) the memcpy is incorrect - it should read  memcpy(pool.memory + offset, object, size);    to make more sense. Not sure if this has been commented yet, apologies if it has.

Answer (score 3):

If you removed the trailing null character, you erased the only info that encoded the string´s length. **There is no way to query the size of the block allocated.**

This is because the terminating zero is C´s way of encoding the string length. Other languages´ runtimes use different methods, like storing the string length (as a byte, or word) in the very first byte pointed to by the string-referencing variable (Delphi for example).

**So there is no way to detect if the trailing null is missing or not.** If it is there, you can search for it. If it is not there, *your search will inevitably access memory locations behind the last byte of the string*, and fail to work correctly.

And because this search (or scan) for the null character is exactly what `strlen` is doing, you cannot use `strlen`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to test if there is a string terminator.

In the first case `str` is automatically sized and the `'\0'` terminator included.

In the second case `xyz` the array size has been defined so there is no room for any terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *pool(char *str, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '\0') {
            return str;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello World";
    char xyz[11] = "Hello World";

    if(pool(str, sizeof str) == NULL) {
        printf("No terminator\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("'%s' is good!\n", str);
    }

    if(pool(xyz, sizeof xyz) == NULL) {
        printf("No terminator\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("'%s' is good!\n", xyz);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
'Hello World' is good!
No terminator
```

Comment: @Dylzan what's the point of asking then? I was simply showing standalone example that checks for a `nul` terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane It appears that `main` is a unit testing suite for a data structure that he is expected to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Since the memory pool is a freeform pool, it's kind of their own fault if they take off the returning null character. However, since you're simply copying the object in `retrieve`, you can add an extra null terminator yourself:

```
void *obj = malloc(size + 1);
*((char*)(obj) + size) = 0; // add the null character
```

With this in place, even if your end user decides to take off a null terminator, one will eventually appear, and it will usually appear in the correct location and thus never cause endless traversal errors that would exist otherwise if there was no null terminator.

Comment: Sorry, it should be a dereference. Editing answer.

Comment: Fixed it - it needed to be the pool's size.

Comment: Actually I misread your question and looked at the code for `retrieve`, and realized that the extra byte should actually be added there.

Comment: But what will happen if you access the last elem? You will eventually access unallocated memory locations, if you do not allocate an extra elem, in addition to the additional byte in every elem. why the hassle when it's so easy to store the length of each elem at the start if each elem (or add an additional zero to each ekem's data)?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Adding an extra zero to the end of the object, in a temp buffer specifically created to account for it, is exactly what this solution is doing.